# Is there any way to take a screenshot with puppeteer and display it automatically on an html page instead of saving it to my computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I am considering using pupeteer for a project I am working on, but I can't seem to figure out if I can take the screenshot taken with puppeteer and display it as an image on an html page automatically. I read through the docs but didn't see anything related to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the image as a `base64` string using the `encoding` option:

```js
const screenshot = await page.screenshot({ encoding: 'base64' });
```

Then you can load that in an HTML as a base64 image:

```
var html = `<img src="data:image/png;base64, ${screenshot}" />`
```